# Summon A No Damage Slime?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if it was possible to summon a slime that didn't hurt you.  I've tried using the "NoAI:1" tag, yes, it makes it unmoving, but it still attacks if you get too close to it.  This is the command I have currently:

```
/summon Slime ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"BeingSlow",NoGravity:1,Invulnerable:1,Size:3,Silent:1,NoAI:1}
```

Comment: the problem with slimes is that there is basically no way to get rid of the way they attack, since their attack is not part of their AI, thus won't be disabled. same with magma-slimes.

Comment: Give the slime a powerful weakness effect? It will still be able to hit you, but its attacks will not do any damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command

```
/summon Slime ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"BeingSlow",NoGravity:1,Invulnerable:1,Size:3,Silent:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:18,Amplifier:10,Duration:999999}]}
```

Will summon a slime with a weakness over 100% meaning every time it will hit you there will be no damage.